# UITabBarController UIViewController View with TabBarCtrl doesn't appear in my ViewCtrl :(

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have **MainController** class for UITabBarController's view managing.

When I try to display my TabBarController from ViewController - it display clear screen. :-( I could display my TabBarController only from __AppDelegate. =)

How can I display TabBarController from my UIViewController based view? =)

Please help me guys. Thank you a lot. =)

**// MainController.h**

```
@interface MainController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITabBarController * tabBarController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController * tabBarController;
@end
```

**I have MyTestAppDelegate:**

**// MyTestAppDelegate.h**

```
#import "MainController.h"    

@class MainController;

@interface MyTestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    MainController * mController;
    IBOutlet UIViewController * viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MainController * mController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController * viewController;

@end
```

**// MyTestAppDelegate.m**

```
#import "MyTestAppDelegate.h"
@implementation MyTestAppDelegate

@synthesize window, mController, viewController;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    MainController * mc = [[MainController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
    self.mController = mc;      
    [mc release];

    [window addSubview:[self.viewController view]];

    [[viewController view] addSubview:[mController.tabBarController view]];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says that UITabBarController has to be on root level. See links and possible workarounds here: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2190703&tstart=0

I have posted full project with working code here, based on code on above thread: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10708521&#10708521